# Invalid column value

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase

I've been working on a script that corrects some links in a few feature classes in an enterprise database I have. The script works fine for the most part. When it gets to a certain feature class my script throws `RuntimeError: Invalid column value [FIELDNAME]`. When I open the feature class's attribute table and manually search for the link I get `There was an error with the expression. Attribute column not found[42s22:[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid colun name'Link I searched for'.][feature class I searched for it in]` Keep in mind that this query was constructed using query builder.

This is the business end of my script:

```
def correct_link_head(compiled_regex, link):
    r"""This function changes the links that start with " A:\\",
"B:\\", "C:\\", and "D:\\" with "other path" so that they actually work."""

    corrected_link = compiled_regex.sub(
        repl = r"\\\\other path\\", string = link)

    return corrected_link


def hyper_link_update_query(feature_class, compiled_regex):
    """This script runs an update cursor on all the feature classes with a hyper link"""
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor( 
        in_table = feature_class, field_names = ["hyperlink_field", ],
        where_clause = "hyperlink_field IS NOT NULL") as cursor:
        for row in cursor:

            row[0] = correct_link_head(
                compiled_regex = compiled_regex, link = str(row[0]))

            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

I've googled this issue every way I can think of. How do I fix this?

Comment: What version of Arc and SQL Server are you using? I wonder if it's a driver issue (seems doubtful if you have other feature classes that are processing fine). Also curious why it's `field_names = ["hyperlink_field", ]` with the comma after it instead of just `field_names = ["hyperlink_field"]`. Didn't know that worked, learn something new everyday.

Comment: @MKF You do `["field_name",]` so that python knows you have a list with one item. I just checked and python seems to be no difference in python 2. Guess I just read it somewhere and thought not doing that caused an issue at some point.

Comment: @MKF I'm using Arc 10.6 and sql server 2017. I'm not sure what the versions are beyond that.

Comment: Maybe try updating the driver? This documentation says you need OBDC Driver 17 when working with SQL Server 2017. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/system-requirements/latest/database-requirements-sqlserver.htm

If that doesn't work, could you post the query you're using when you manually try to get at the link through query builder?

Comment: @mkf The query is in the question. I changed the field names that's it.

Comment: Have you narrowed it down to that specific link? Will it find any other link if you query manually?

Comment: @mkf actually I don't think the link is even in the table since the table is unchanged, but it shouldn't be throwing an error when I try to select it like that. The query I use to select it is `hyperlink_field = "other path\some more path stuff"`. The link changes every time I run the code too.

Comment: So your code works fine with some feature classes but not with others. That  seems to rule out a field name problem if they all have the same table structure. Doesn't necessarily rule out regex if it gets stuck on the same feature class with the same link every time you run it (I'm imagining the link(s) changes with the feature class but the links associated with that fc don't change every run). Arc is pretty notorious for throwing misleading errors. I have seen some really weird, nonsensical ones when my driver is not up to date, so that's all I can really suggest here. Sorry can't help more!

Comment: @mkf You're helping a lot as it is. Thanks! I have since determined that I'm on sql server 2016.

Comment: So it must not be a driver issue then. Dang. Are you able to share the actual name of your field (assuming it is not 'hyperlink_field')? Is it any one of these reserved words? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @MKF It's not anything reserved... The other feature class it has problems with just throws `SystemError: error return without exception set`